# 500 Internal server error while logout in php

Tags: php, wampserver

I am using wamp server.
Error is : The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
While i am clicking on logout it is redirecting to this error.
Code
logout.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header('location:login.php');
?>
```

login.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>login and registration</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "container">
        <div class ="login-box">
        <div class = "row">
            <div class = "col-md-6 login-left">
                <h2>Login here</h2>
                <form action = "validation.php" method="post">
                    <div class = "form-group">
                        <label>Username</label>
                        <input type = "text" name ="user" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "form-group">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type = "Password" name ="password" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                </form>
            </div>  
            <div class = "col-md-6 login-right">
                <h2>Register here</h2>
                <form action = "registration.php" method="post">
                    <div class = "form-group">
                        <label>Username</label>
                        <input type = "text" name ="user" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "form-group">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type = "Password" name ="password" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                </form>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the web-servers error log to see the actual error message.

Comment: Can you add all the code relating to the logout? This includes the button itself and any events and functions that it triggers

Comment: before header redirect make sure nothing is being rendered. Your code needs more descriptions. You can comment on each line from the bottom of logout.php and debug.